# Curried functions and function application in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm working on a language very similar to STLC that I'm converting to Z3 propositions, hence a few (sub)questions about how Z3 treats (uninterpreted) functions:

1. Functions are naturally curried in my language and as I'm converting the terms of my language recursively, I'd like to be able to build the corresponding Z3 AST recursively as well. That is, when I have a term `f x y` I'd like to first apply `f` to `x` and then apply that to `y`. Is there a way to do this? The API I've found so far (`Z3_mk_func_decl`/`Z3_mk_app`) seems to require me to collect all arguments first and apply them all at once.
2. Is there a reasonable way to represent something like `(if b then f else g) x`?

In both cases, I'm totally fine with functions being uninterpreted and restricting the reasoning to things like "`b = True /\ f x = 0 => (if b then f else g) x = 0` holds".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMTLib (as described in http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf) is a many-sorted first-order logic. All functions (uninterpreted or not) must be applied to all its arguments, and you cannot have any form of currying. Also, you cannot do higher-order if-then-else, i.e., the branches of an if-then-else will have to be first-order values. (However, they can be arrays, and you can imagine "faking" functions with arrays. But that's besides the point.)

It should be noted that the next iteration of SMTLib (v3) will be based on a higher-order logic, at which point features like you're asking might become available. See: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/version3.shtml. Of course, this is still a proposal and it'll take a while before it's settled and actual solvers start implementing it faithfully. Eventually that'll happen, but I wouldn't expect it in the very near term.

Aside: Since you mentioned STLC (simply-typed-lambda-calculus), I presume you might be familiar with functional languages like Haskell. If that's the case, you might want to look into using SBV: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv. It provides a framework for doing some of these things by carefully translating them away behind the scenes. Here's an example:

```hs
Prelude Data.SBV> sat $ \b -> (ite b (uninterpret "f") (uninterpret "g")) (0::SInteger) .== (0::SInteger)
Satisfiable. Model:
  s0 = True :: Bool

  f :: Integer -> Integer
  f _ = 0

  g :: Integer -> Integer
  g _ = 2
```

Here we created two functions and used the `ite` construct to "merge" them; and got the solver to return us a model. Behind the scenes, SBV will fully saturate these applications and let you "pretend" you're programming in a higher-order sense, just like in STLC or Haskell. Of course, the devil is in the details and there are limitations to the approach, but modeling STLC in Haskell is a classic pastime for many people and doing it symbolically using SBV can be a fun exercise.

Comment: Thanks! Well, looks like I'll have to wait until smtlib v3 then. And thanks for pointing me to sbv! In fact my implementation is indeed in Haskell, although I'm using haskell-z3 right now. I've seen sbv before but kind of shrugged it off not seeing any reason in deviating from more "classical" solvers, but now I'm at the point where it becomes reasonable. Maybe I should reconsider my solver choice.